# probability. sampling with replacement

Tags: probability, statistics

Initially, an urn contains three white and five red balls. Balls are drawn at random
from the urn. Whenever a red ball is drawn, it is placed back into the urn together
with one extra red ball. Whenever a white ball is drawn, it is placed back into the
urn together with two extra white balls. Find the probability that the first three balls
drawn out of the urn alternate in colour.

I am not entirely sure what "alternate in colour" means. Does that mean that the balls can't all have the same colour or that the same colour cannot be picked twice in a row?

Comment: Yes, I take "alternate in color" to mean the draws are Red, White, Red or White, Red, White.

Comment: @kccu thank you! do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Hints: Initially, the probability of drawing a red ball is $\dfrac{5}{8}$ since there are 5 red balls and 8 total balls. After drawing a red ball, there are 6 red balls and 3 white balls. So, the probability of the second ball being white after drawing a red ball would be...

Comment: There are two ways to get 'alternate in color': red, white, red, or white,red ,white. So, calculate the probability of each of those, and then just add them up

Comment: oh ok that's what I did but I thought it should be more formal. Thank you

Comment: If you update your question to include the work you have done for it, the community can help further (if you are correct, we can verify, and if something is not quite right, we can discuss it further).